# Unzip the File in Objective C for(iphone App)

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have implemented one iphone application in which i have download one zip file from the server and downloaded in iphone.Now i want to extract zip file by programming.I dont know how it possible and where the extract data will store.

Advance Thanz.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [nice class](http://www.flyblog.info/catprogramming/202.html) for zipping and unzipping files on the iPhone. Good luck!

Comment: tnz u.. Am new to iphone so need how to integrate tht code...
i need some sample code for unzip